# How to nagivate to created item in Angular

Tags: angular, routes

I'm adding a new Recipe. After that i want to navigate to new added recipe.

How should i pass created recipe's id?

I've tried:
 this.router.navigate(['/recipe/edit/' + id]);

but it doesn't navigate me there. 
In response i got :
 http://localhost:5000/api/recipes/%7Bid%7D 400 (Bad Request)

[image]

```
this.router.navigate(['/recipe/edit/HERE MUST BE ID CREATED RECIPE']);
```

My add-recipe.component.ts

```
@Component({
      selector: 'app-add-recipe',
      templateUrl: './add-recipe.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./add-recipe.component.css']
    })
    export class AddRecipeComponent implements OnInit {
      categories: Category[];
      user: User;
      recipe: Recipe;
      addRecipeForm: FormGroup;
      constructor(private fb: FormBuilder,
                  private alertifyService: AlertifyService,
                  private router: Router,
                  private recipeService: RecipeService, private authService: AuthService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.createRecipeForm();
    this.getCategories();
  }


  createRecipeForm() {
    this.addRecipeForm = this.fb.group({
      name: ['', Validators.required],
      ingredients: ['', Validators.required],
      preparationTime: ['', Validators.required],
      description: ['', Validators.required],
      categoryId: ['', Validators.required]
    });
  }


  createRecipe(id: number) {
    if (this.addRecipeForm.valid) {
      this.recipe = Object.assign({}, this.addRecipeForm.value);
      this.recipeService.addNewRecipe(this.authService.currentUser.id, this.recipe).subscribe(() => {
        this.alertifyService.success('New recipe has been added!');
      }, error => {
        this.alertifyService.error(error);
      }, () => {
          this.router.navigate(['/recipe/edit/']);
        });
    }
  }

  cancel() {
    this.router.navigate(['members']);
    this.alertifyService.warning('Cancelled');
  }
```

Comment: What do you mean? This maybe: `this.router.navigate([\`/recipe/edit/${yourIdHere}\`]);` ? It does not work is *not* a good description of a problem. Please be specific, what happens exactly.

Comment: In response i get:  http://localhost:5000/api/recipes/%7Bid%7D 400 (Bad Request. Navigation is not working

Comment: @Igor How should i pass created recipe's id?

Comment: @BartolV9 what is the response of the `addNewRecipe` service ?

Comment: {"errors":{"id":["The value '${id}' is not valid."]}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must be getting the `id`  of created item in the `response` of the `addNewRecipe` service.
This is how you should navigate :

```
this.recipeService.addNewRecipe(this.authService.currentUser.id, this.recipe)
     .subscribe((result) => {
        this.alertifyService.success('New recipe has been added!');
        let id = result.id;
         this.router.navigate([`/recipe/edit/${id}`]);
      }, error => {
        this.alertifyService.error(error);
      });
```